# Error when require Realm in react native app

Tags: react-native, realm

I'm integrating Realm in my react native project and I get an error when I use the import statement defined on the realm documentation.

```
const Realm = require('realm');
```

I've followed all the steps on the web, but still getting the error. This is the output error from Xcode:

```
2018-05-31 11:11:53.037 [fatal][tid:com.facebook.react.ExceptionsManagerQueue] Unhandled JS Exception: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'self.fetch')
2018-05-31 11:11:53.036887+0200 wallet-development[1734:651340] Unhandled JS Exception: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'self.fetch')
2018-05-31 11:11:53.040 [warn][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Unable to symbolicate stack trace: Requiring module "fetch", which threw an exception: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'self.fetch')
2018-05-31 11:11:53.040236+0200 wallet-development[1734:651343] Unable to symbolicate stack trace: Requiring module "fetch", which threw an exception: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'self.fetch')
```

And this one what I get on the phone:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

FYI: I could fix the issue by adding these lines just before importing the realm.

```
if (typeof global.self === 'undefined') {
  global.self = global;
}
```

I found the possible fix here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9599